# Python regex: one or more occurrences of a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Suppose I have strings like these:

1. `"DT NN IN NN"`
2. `"NN IN NN"`
3. `"NN NN IN NN"`
4. `"NN IN NN NN NN"`
5. `"NN NN IN NN NN"`
6. `"CD NN IN CD NN"`
7. `"NN IN NN DT"`

Basically I have a list of strings:

```
list = ["DT NN IN NN", "NN IN NN", "NN NN IN NN", "NN IN NN NN NN", "NN NN IN NN NN", "CD NN IN CD NN", "NN IN NN DT"]
```

Suppose that I want to match the patterns that start and have one or more `NN`, followed by `IN`, followed by one or more `NN` (or `(NN+) (IN) (NN+)`). This would mean that if I want the matches of these, I will get a positive hit on strings 2 through 5, and negative on 1, 6 and 7 (it needs to end with NN).

One of the things I've tried is with `re`:

```
pattern = "(NN+) (IN) (NN+)"
for item in list:
    m = re.match(pattern, item)
    if m:
        print item
```

But this prints only `NN IN NN` and `NN IN NN NN NN` but not the rest.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You seem to have the regex you want, where have you got in implementing that in Python? Are the strings in a list? Are you iterating over it? Using the `re` module?

Comment: Yes, I am iterating over a list of strings and want to match the strings as I showed (the thing I showed is not exactly a regex, but I think it shows what I want).

Comment: And which part is the problem? Writing the correct regex? Applying it to all of the items? Could you show an [mcve] of some actual Python code that demonstrates where you're stuck?

Comment: I've added actual code + more details. Sorry if my questions was not clear enough, I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

```
^((?:NN\s+)+)IN\s+NN
```

For ending with NN, use:

```
^(?:NN\s+)+IN\s+(?:NN\s+)*NN$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT9rQ4/2)**

In your regex

```
(NN+) (IN) (NN+)
```

The first `N` matches `N` literally and `N+` matches one or more `N`. 
In simple terms it matches `N` followed by `N` one or more times, while you want to match `NN` any number of times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please give me a Python code of how to implement this?

Comment: @Belphegor did you try replacing the regex in your current snippet with this one? `pattern = r'^((?:NN\s+)+)IN\s+NN'`

Comment: OK, I got it to work as you said, but only partially. When a pattern doesn't end with NN, it still gives me a positive hit. How do I limit the regex so it will end with NN?

Comment: @Belphegor you did not said anything about matching in end

Comment: @Belphegor you can use `^(?:NN\s+)+IN\s+(?:NN\s+)*NN$`

Comment: Sorry about that, just noticed I forgot to mention it. I've edited my question.

Comment: @Belphegor glad to help..just read about match that it matches only in starting of string..so no need of `^` here if you are using `re.match`..at a point you may require `re.search`